# orderbyvalue fuction in android does not work?

Tags: android, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sort by highscore values and I have searched for examples like here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

But still it doesn't work. I have tried to Log every step that I take but still no results. Please help me with this.

[image: Firebase]

[image: My code where I use sort]

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: In the picture!

Comment: have you tried with this ?
Query queryRef = highscoreRef.orderByValue();
and than set `addChildEventListener` on `queryRef`

Comment: For future questions: don't post pictures of text (JSON or code) please. Instead post the actual text, so that it can be searched and copy/pasted when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It  should be like this:

```
highScoreRef.orderByValue().addChildEventListener( ... ) { ... }
```

or if you want to save `Query` object first:

```
Query query = highScoreRef.orderByValue();
query.addChildEventListener( ... ) { ... }
```